# jQuery masonry plugin Inside an Accodion, a complex integration

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-masonry, jquery-ui-accordion

Getting a hard time to resolve  the issue, and also very hard to explain the scenario, so I am attaching an image, explaining what I want to achieve. see the image below
[image]

Now, I am using a custom code to invoke the panels, a simple jquery script, something like this

```
$('.widgets_area').find('.widget_title').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
              $(this).next().slideToggle('fast')
}
```

Once the panel opened, I want to get items inside that panel as jquery.masonry plugin items, because when some one click on the Items it will expand to down and show some description, also want to arrange in order, as seen in image below.

So I have prepared a fiddle here, with what I have achieved so far, there is some issues, now with my script I can show the panels, and also masonry items inside those panels, but only for the first Panel the expanding thing on masonry items works well, thinks like there is some binding issues, but I am not able resolve the issue, any help will be appreciated.

Here is the Fiddle,  with complete html,css,and js, please check this for idea about what I am trying to explain about the issue.

fiddle: [Masnory+Accordion](http://jsfiddle.net/0bukn3kg/3/)

Comment: I think you have only written scripts for `$('.grid').masonry()` and `$('.grid2').masonry()` not for `$('.grid3').masonry()` this script needs to be dynamic for all grids.

Comment: @IndrasinhBihola - Ok I have missed out that, I have updated the fiddle, please check now. can you please explain about - script needs to be dynamic for all grids!!

Comment: Dynamic means it's needs to work at any depth. You need to write some generic code that works for all elements.

Comment: @IndrasinhBihola thank you, waiting for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.widgets_area').find('.widget_title').on('click', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
$(this).next().slideToggle('fast', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.prev().addClass('wd_act');
    $this.parent().addClass('wd_open');

    var $grid2 = $($this).children().first().masonry({
        columnWidth: 0,
        itemSelector: '.grid-item'
    });

    $grid2.on('click', '.widget_bx', function () {
        //alert('dsaf');
        $(this).next('.wd_info').toggle();
        $(this).parent('.grid-item').toggleClass('is-expanded');
        $grid2.masonry();
    });

});
//Hide the other panels
$(".wd_list_wrap").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');
$(".wd_list_wrap").not($(this).next()).prev('.widget_title').removeClass('wd_act');
$(".wd_list_wrap").not($(this).next()).parent().removeClass('wd_open');

});
```

I think this might work for you I have only replace static element with dynamic one like this:

**Static:**

```
var $grid2 = $('.grid2')
```

**Dynamic:**

```
var $grid2 = $($this).children().first()
```

**Note:** Now you don't need to place seperate script for each elements.

Fiddle: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/biholaindrasinh/0bukn3kg/13/)

Comment: thanks for that, but there is some issues. If you dont mind, in your fiddle, if I go through each panel on first time, everything working fine, but when I go back to the previous panel on second time, the click on the 'masonry item-* ' is not working, means not expanding or closing the items, if you try open and close the panels repeatedly it works again, that was the real issue I was facing. please check .

Comment: I hope you are checking bug, as I said in my question, seems some thing like event binding issue. Because If I open any panel first time Everything works fine, but if I close that panel, and open again the masonry item will not expane,ie click on that not working, If I close the panel and open it again, starts working...

Comment: I have tested it and it's working in my fiddle :https://jsfiddle.net/biholaindrasinh/0bukn3kg/13/

Comment: It's ok dear.. It's my pleasure.

Comment: if you dont mind, on more question, I can see there is jerking on when opening new panel, can we fix that??? just an extra help ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91367/discussion-between-indrasinh-bihola-and-salih-k).